# ASP.Net MVC Single-Sign On

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

We're in a period of moving all our applications to sub-domains of the same primary domain.

Once this is done we aim to move our entire set up to a Single Sign-On system. Currently, we use Forms authentication and set a cookie containing an encrypted token when the user is successfully logged in.

When it comes to setting this up for SSO - is it simply a matter of changing the domain to which the session cookie(s) are set? Or are there other matters that need addressing for this to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the Machine key in the system.web section of your we.config's to the same value, get that from your IIS config:

```
<machineKey validationKey="<from IIS>" decryptionKey="<from IIS>"
validation="SHA1" decryption="3DES" />
```

Then all the sites will see the cookie as valid. The domain names in your  section should be subdomains, I think. Well, it works when they are subdomains, don't know what it will do if the actual domain names are different.

Comment: The browser won't send the cookie if the domains are different for security reasons.

Comment: one of those little things that I spent about 20 hours figuring out a few years ago. Security is such a PITA.

Comment: This will work using forms authentication if you specify the domain (leading period is important) `<forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" domain=".mydomain.com" />` and the above machineKey is the same on both machines.