# Options for single sign-on between ASP.NET and MVC.NET solutions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, authentication

I have an ASP.NET solution that acts as the primary customer portal for my customers.  On this website the users can log-in access their important financial information and more.  The website uses a custom authentication scheme that checks the user's username (their email) and their password (salt-hashed) against a `Users` table in a local database.

I am building a new MVC.NET solution that is more of a web-app tool to be used by these same customers for ordering.  I want to re-use the sign-on mechanism of the ASP.NET portal to authenticate users.  The goal is to save the user from remembering two log-ins or even having to supply the same log-in twice.

What are my options for allowing users who sign on to the ASP.NET solution to then be auto authenticated to the MVC.NET solution?  I've listed some ideas below but are these "bad" or is there a more elegant solution?  I'd love your input.

- **Common Cookie**  I could create a common cookie that the ASP.NET site creates and the MVC.NET site looks for.  But is that secure enough?
- **Token in Query String**  I could create a token id on the ASP.NET site that is stored in the local database and is then passed in the query string of the link to the MVC.NET site which takes the token id and validates it against the same database.
- **Hybrid**  A bit of both?
- **Other?**  Got a better idea?

Comment: I'd recommend you to take a look to Windows Identity Foundation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.Net MVC Single-Sign On](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176426/asp-net-mvc-single-sign-on)

Comment: More info about [Stack Exchanges Global Network Auto-Login](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/global-network-auto-login/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've recently done something quite similar (the major difference being that it was internal to the company rather than for external customers) using [OpenId](http://openid.net/).

The implementation of OpenId for .NET is called [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/) which should be suitable for your purposes.

It did take me a while to implement; but it works very well, is very flexible, and extremely secure.

More information about openid (from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID)):

> OpenID is an open standard that allows users to be authenticated by certain co-operating sites (known as Relying Parties or RP) using a third party service, eliminating the need for webmasters to provide their own ad hoc systems and allowing users to consolidate their digital identities.
>
> Users may create accounts with their preferred OpenID identity providers, and then use those accounts as the basis for signing on to any website which accepts OpenID authentication. The OpenID standard provides a framework for the communication that must take place between the identity provider and the OpenID acceptor (the "relying party").[2](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/) An extension to the standard (the OpenID Attribute Exchange) facilitates the transfer of user attributes, such as name and gender, from the OpenID identity provider to the relying party (each relying party may request a different set of attributes, depending on its requirements).
>
> The OpenID protocol does not rely on a central authority to authenticate a user's identity. **Moreover, neither services nor the OpenID standard may mandate a specific means by which to authenticate users**, allowing for approaches ranging from the common (such as passwords) to the novel (such as smart cards or biometrics).

Oh, and if you'd like further encouragement, Stack Exchange uses it!

@Jmrnet: in response to your last comment:

Perhaps I was unclear. OpenId in and of itself is simply for validating credentials from one location to another (more or less). It's entirely possible to implement as an SSO model where users do nothing different whatsoever - they don't have to choose a provider, or register, or anything like that. For example, in my setup, the user enters a username and password in a web portal, and then clicks a button to launch another site being automatically logged in by OpenId. Nothing different for the user at all! OpenId can be used with any initial authentication model you can think of (note the bolded section in the snippet from wikipedia).

Comment: I like this idea.  I cant use OpenId itself but can this be used with a home grown auth of some kind?

Comment: @jmrnet Why can't you use OpenId? You could roll your own version of this kind of thing, yes...but in order to make it secure enough you'd practically be rewriting the openid standard...in which case you should just use openId :)

Comment: @IamStalker I'd recommend the sample projects that come with Dotnetopenauth. I'll elaborate a bit on the basic principle of openid.

Comment: There are a few reasons I cant use openid like: users a not savvy, we have to vet customers and create accounts for them before they can get access, and a few others.  However, thanks for this info.  I'll consider it.

Comment: @Mansfield Ah!  I see.  I like this.  It will take some research but it sounds pretty promising.  Thanks for your input!

Comment: @jmrnet No problem! If you have any technical questions let me know, I'll do my best to answer those as well. Also the creator of DotNetOpenAuth posts pretty regularly on here and he's very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at SAML:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language

It works using XML and supports encryption.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently implementing two SSO solutions for the same project.

In one, we are interfacing with an external partner and are using SAML.

In the other, we are allowing logged in users access to our Sharepoint and using the "Token in Query String" approach, since we trust Sharepoint to access our membership tables. This approach is much easier than dealing with SAML tokens.

Comment: This was my initial thought, but I worry that passing the token in the query string isnt secure enough.  Am I being overly worried?

Comment: You should not expose it as clear text. We use a GUID as the record identifier, then we encrypt it and finally, base64 encode it so we can include it in the QS.

Answer (score 0):

There are many methods you can use, Mansfied described OpenID and RandomUs1r described SAML. Also, you can store relevant information in localStorage or in the session. I believe you should store relevant information with session.

It is not safe to put this in the query string, because if I register and log in, I will see something like UserID=1234 in the URL. If I change that to UserID=1235 and the ID is existent, then I can do some things in the name of the other user. This is called identity theft, which should be prevented by any means possible. So you should never have this kind of info in your URLs. Also, if you store the id of the user, you should obfuscate it somehow. For instance if you store the value in local storage and instead of 1234 you store encrypt(1234, salt), then the consistency of user action will be maintained.